How to find auto-generated App registration/Service principal tied to a service connection
I have about a dozen Azure DevOps (cloud version) service connections and for each I have also an App registration and Service principal in MS Entra, all named the same:
<organization>-<project>-<subscription id>

I need a way to find which App registration is related to which Service connection in Azure DevOps. This can be done easily if the service connection is of "Azure Resource Manager" type, as there is a link that takes me directly into the service principal.
However, other connections like Docker registry, Kubernetes or "Other Git", I don't see any indication of what exactly is this connection's principal, no ID, no nothing.
What I see when editing ACR service connection:
I have all the access to my Azure subscription and also DevOps, so I should have visibility for everything.
Tried looking around both but cannot find any link that would help me find the correct SP.

I found the solution in Azure DevOps CLI.
First need to authenticate your shell with Azure DevOps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops
When successful, you need to run the following command:
az devops service-endpoint list --org <org URI> --project <project name>

This command will output a JSON with information about all the connections set up in your project, including relevant Service Principal IDs (if used).
When you paste the SP ID in the Azure Portal search box, you will find your SP/App Registration.
